# Message passing between processes

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, exe

We've built a dll that we're using throughout our projects. Now, due to several reasons, we need to have that as an executable, but the problem is that it integrates with other solutions by throwing events.

If we move it to be an executable how can we transform our code to maintain the functionality of events? (it can no longer reference the exe directly, it has to call it as a process)

Comment: You assembly can not thow the events, only the code classes, methods, can throw the events, not the assembly.

Comment: So you can move the code whick requires the main body into the separate executable appication, whilst leav almost all the code intact in original dll assembly.

Answer (score 1):

For interprocess communication, see named pipes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do nothing since exe assemblies references as well as dll assemblies. The other stuff is up to you. If you are aware of accessing the executable while it is running, create another startup executable project directly referencing this executable, then run new executable using old executable.

Second question, why to do things so hard? Why not using the dll assemblies to share the code between projects?

To summarize, you can move the code which requires the main(..) body into the separate executable appication, whilst leaveing all the code intact in the original assembly dll.

Comment: It's a licencing issue - the assembly we built works unchanged in various scenarios, but, in order to be built when inside the solution every developer must have licences for every component in that dll. So, if we make an exe out of .dll, the licences are included in it, and there's no need for every user of exe to have a separate licence.

Comment: @veljkoz I don't understand. What needs licensed? If it is some 3rd party library (DLL), nothing changes, the DLLs are still independent entities, whether or not *your* code is a DLL or EXE. DLLs are never included *in* an EXE.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart If you're using 3rd party dll in your solution it requires a license in order for you to build & deploy your solution (e.g. infragistics, teleric, etc). And that's OK for the components you actually are designing. But there are some components that are part of your solution that don't need any designing anymore and you want to distribute them around as complete, without the need for every developer that's using it to have a separate license of its own. So, instead of building dll that would have to reference a license, you could output exe instead that doesn't require one.